# Corruption of contentsURL encoding type?

Tags: ios, swift, url, encoding

I am still struggling with accessing certain Google pages and have tried multiple combinations of encoding types.  I've also tried UTF8 and then falling through to a default if that fails.  This is where things get very odd.

I do the following:

```
println("URL within process page = \(url)")

println("Trying NSUTF8")
origURLString = String(contentsOfURL: url, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)
if (error != nil) {
    println("Error = \(error)")
    println("Trying NSASCII next")
    origURLString = String(contentsOfURL: url, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding, error: &error)
    if (error != nil) {
        println("Error = \(error)")
    }
}

if (error != nil) {
    return "There seems to be a problem going to this site"
}
```

Both calls to contentsOfURL fail with the following trace:

> Trying NSUTF8
>   Error = Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=261 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 261.)" UserInfo=0x7fbbda599b00 {NSURL=http://www.google.com/search?ie=ISO-8859-1&hl=en-GB&source=hp&q=hello&btnG=Google+Search&gbv=1, NSStringEncoding=4})
>
> Trying NSASCII next
>   Error = Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=261 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 261.)" UserInfo=0x7fbbda599b00 {NSURL=http://www.google.com/search?ie=ISO-8859-1&hl=en-GB&source=hp&q=hello&btnG=Google+Search&gbv=1, NSStringEncoding=4})

However, if I don't try using NSUTF8StringEncoding and just use ASCII encoding:

```
origURLString = String(contentsOfURL: url, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding, error: &error)
```

Then this works (not so well since the encoding isn't right). No error code at least, and I get a full HTML page.

Obviously, I can't use ASCII encoding for everything and I would rather build a general approach that checks UFT8 first before defaulting to something else.

Am I corrupting something with my first approach?  Is the error message carrying over?

I tried testing every NSEncodingType in a loop and that failed, so I narrowed it down to just two and I get the same issue.

Ideas?  I'm at a complete loss.

Answer (score 0):

**This function helps me correct my text strings:**

```
func utf(txt:String)->NSString{
        var newtxt = txt.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\n", withString: " ", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
        if var scb = NSString(CString: newtxt ,encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding){
            return scb
        }else{
            var scb = NSString(CString:newtxt, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            return scb!
        }
    }
```

> This is interesting because it occupies the encoding that fits
>   according to the text string to be sent.

Comment: Thanks Elias. That looks like a really good general encoding routine, but I'm not sure how it helps with the URL content issue, or explain why doing a UTF request before an ASCII request prevents the ASCII request from working.

Comment: You can I start trying to `HTTPTask()` on Swift [swiftHTTP](https://github.com/daltoniam/swiftHTTP) well said that 261 error is due to SSL Certificate